# Design principle DRY in C?

Tags: c, performance, design-patterns

My Question for larger coding perspective but I'm trying to understand with simple example. Lets say I have few lines of Code

```
int main(void) {
    int input_1 = 10;
    int input_2 = 10;
    /* some stuff */
    return 0;
}
```

After reading design principles(I am not sure whether it was common for programming language or not, I hope its generic) I came to know that *above code is valid C code but its a **dirty code** because here I'm not following **DRY**(Don't repeat yourself) principle* as magic number `10` is repeating.

Firstly My doubt is, Does **C** standard  says the same about best practices of coding, I read specs but I didn't get exactly ?

And I modified as below to avoid the phrase Dirty Code

```
int main(void) { /* I'm not 100 percent sure that this is not dirty code ? */
    const int value = 10; /*assigning 10 to const variable*/
    int input_1 = value; 
    int input_2 = value;  
    /* some stuff */
    return 0;
}
```

Does modified version is the correct or can I do something more better in that ? Finally If these design principles are best suggested than why compilers doesn't produce any warning.

Comment: Did you mean to write `20` in the first snippet?

Comment: 1. You're *not* assigning `10` to both. 2. You don't need to take DRY to the *nth* degree. There's such a thing as *too dogmatically DRY*. Code needs some moisture too.

Comment: @achal the C standard defines the language. It doesn't care about style and design, which is independent of any language to some degree.

Comment: The C standard doesn't say jack about best practices. Neither does a frightening amount of C programming books. Therefore things like this boil down to programmer experience. Which in turn is sad - there is no reason why we can't teach best practices to beginners.

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen So its completely programmer responsibility to  follow the designs rule while coding.

Comment: @achal:  that is particularly so with C where we sometimes have to go *off piste* (that's why we are using C).  It is a balance between cost of maintenance and runtime costs, but not *always*.  That balance decision has to be made soberly, not on a whim.

Comment: True I agree @cdarke  `const` example is not good but that's better than first code I mentioned performance wise.

Comment: @achal performance has nothing to do with it. Well, almost, if your compiler doesn't optimize your `value` away, the second version takes a bit more memory and runtime.

Comment: Agree @FelixPalmen I just mentioned the few line of code to make my question programmatic. My concern about design principle, should I follow all design principle like YAGNI, KISS etc while writing code in `C`.

Comment: @achal that's your decision. If it's beneficial, follow it.

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen I got your point.

Comment: yes @Bathsheba it was misprint. both `input_1` and `input_1` are `10`.

Comment: @achal: Bit late now ;-) For what it's worth I am in disagreement with the accepted answer; the introduction of macros is very polluting. I'd be tempted to write `input_1 = input_2 = 10;` but then that messes up the declaration. So, on balance, I'd leave things as they are. You can overdo the DRY concept.

Comment: Thanks @Bathsheba so if its `input_1 = input_2 = 10;` then we can't say its DRY.

Comment: @achal: Well it would be DRY but then you're separating declaration from initialisation which is ruinous for program stability and is to be avoided. Perhaps one day `C` might get some weird syntax so you could write `auto [input_1, input_2] = {10};` and be done with it.

Comment: yes true @Bathsheba. Generally we shouldn't keep any uninitialized variable in our code & most of the variable we are initializing with `0(zero)`, In that case magic number `0` is repeated, correct me If am wrong i.e that also come under don't repeat yourself?

Comment: @achal: Wow you are taking this DRY concept to heart! Let's regard 0 as a special case. In C++ we have `{}` for zero initialisation, which is nice.

Comment: No, I was reading Design principles so these doubts came to my mind i.e why author was saying like that. Anyway thanks for your nice explanation.

Comment: @achal: Sorry, got a day job to be getting on with.

Comment: May I know the reason of down votes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more about avoiding **magic numbers**. Your `10` should have **some** semantic meaning if you claim it's "*the same 10*". Then you should do something like

```
#define FROBNUM 10 // use a name here that explains the meaning of the number

int main(void) {
    int input_1 = FROBNUM; 
    int input_2 = FROBNUM;  
    /* some stuff */
    return 0;
}
```

Introducing a `const` is unnecessary, macros solve this problem nicely. DRY is addressed here, the macro definition is the single source of the concrete value.

---

If there is on the other hand **no semantic relationship** between the two 10 values, `#define` two macros instead. This isn't "repeating yourself" if they indeed have a different meaning. Don't misunderstand DRY here.

---

Side note about your version with `const`: It has two flaws

- The name `value` isn't semantic at all, so nothing gained, the number is still *magic*
- With this declaration, you introduce a new object of automatic storage duration and type `int`, which you don't really need. A good compiler would optimize it away, but better not rely on that -- that's why a macro fits better here.

Answer (score 3):

DRY mostly refers to there being *one single source of truth*. Certain business rules or reusable code patterns should only be expressed once, *especially if they may be altered in the future.* Examples include code to calculate shipping fees or tax rates, which you want to code exactly once and alter exactly in one place if they change; or the instantiation of a database adapter which you can alter in exactly one place when the database details change.

DRY does not mean that you must reduce every line of code which looks similar to another line of code into one single line.